# Earth Resistivity Test on concrete base

Tags: grounding, testing, test-equipment, earth, resistivity

I am planning to conduct an Earth Resistivity Test on my property. The issue is that my building's basement is entirely covered with concrete and pavement, and we intended to use the Fall-of-Potential test method since there are no other equipment options available for rent in my location. However, I am unable to place the probes wherever I need to take the readings. Therefore, I have a few questions:

1. Is it possible to use the other earthing rod/pit as one of the probes?
2. Does the length of the probe matter? If yes, what changes may require in calculation of resistivity?
3. Is there an alternative method to perform the test without expensive equipment?
4. What are the best practices for situations like these?

Comment: What is your purpose for testing earth resistivity?

Comment: Hmm. Just doing a search i found [this discussion](https://netaworldjournal.org/earth-resistivity-test-methods-and-evaluations/). Might be helpful.

Comment: Don;t use other earthing rod as reference since all the rods might be connected together underneath by an iron wire. (I have no answer for the other questions )